# One element fill the whole screen after another gets Invisible?

Tags: android, visibility

How to make `TextView` fill the whole screen after the `Button` gets invisible?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Button gets invisible via menu item command

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: what do you mean by fill the whole screen, do you mean set the width and height of the TextView to the width and the height of the screen? or increase the font size?

Comment: Yes. And is the 2nd feature (font increase) possible at all in Android? It does not have auto-fill for font like the iPhone has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

[More Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Quote from that page:

> int   GONE    This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.